# How to change the color of the titlebar in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I need to change the color of the titlebar to white color . What is the steps to be done Without using sass. I should be able to do that without theming in sencha touch.

Comment: Why not sass?  It's the supported way...

Comment: How to use in worklight

Answer (score 0):

Here is the style which you have to add in your css file.

```
.x-toolbar-dark {
   background-color: white !important;
   background-image: none !important;
}
```

By adding this style, you are simply overriding the sencha titlebar's default styling and now color of titlebar will become white.

NB: I would prefer you to use SASS if possible. Comment here if you need to change your sass file. Thank you.